# Check if node exists in h5py

Tags: python, h5py

I am wondering if there is a simple way to check if a node exists within an HDF5 file using h5py.

I couldn't find anything in the docs, so right now I'm using exceptions, which is ugly.

```
# check if node exists
# first assume it exists
e = True
try:
  h5File["/some/path"]
except KeyError:
  e = False # now we know it doesn't
```

To add context: I'm using this to determine if a node exists before trying to create a new node with the same name.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
e = "/some/path" in h5File
```

does it. This is very briefly mentioned in [the `Group` documentation](https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#h5py.Group.__contains__).

Answer (score 3):

You can also simply use `require_group()` method for groups. [H5py Docs.](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.require_group)

Answer (score 1):

After checking the documentation at [group docs](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/high/group.html). I assume you can use the keys method of the group object to check before usage:

```
# check if node exists
# first assume it doesn't exist
e = False
node = "/some/path"
if node in h5file.keys():
    h5File[node]
    e = True
```

Comment: In Python 2, this will actually load the entire set of keys into a list and then do linear search over this list, whereas using `__contains__` (i.e. `"/some/path" in h5file`) will check it much more directly. Also, it won't work for the example given, only if it's a top-level member.

Comment: I considered this, but it doesn't work for embedded members. Also, I was not aware of the efficiency implications... thanks!