# How to feed a regular expression to a method that requires a string?

Tags: python, regex, h5py

What I want to achieve is based on the voted answer for a previous question: [Check if node exists in h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753418/check-if-node-exists-in-h5py)

Basically I want to replace:

```
"/some/path" in h5File
```

with something like:

```
import re
re.compile(r'/some/[pattern]+') in h5File
```

Comment: You can't, that doesn't make sense. Unless the `__contains__` method than implements `in` is written to accept a compiled regular expression, or you can get the actual string to match against, there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` keyword can't take a regex, but you could use list-comprehension or `filter` built-in to get all keys from a dictionary that match a given regex.

E.g.

```
found_keys = [k for k in h5file if re.match(r'/some/[pattern]+', k)]
```

or

```
regex = re.compile(r'/some/[pattern]+')
found_keys = filter(regex.match, h5file)
```

Comment: Also, if Hailiang only wants to check whether there is a matching key, it is possible to merely call `any(regex.match(k) for k in h5file)`.