# Does h5py offer a neat simple way to create or use a group or dataset?

Tags: h5py

I'm fixing a python script using h5py.  It contains code like this:

```
hdf = h5py.File(hdf5_filename, 'a')
... 
g = hdf.create_group('foo')
g.create_dataset('bar', ...whatever...)
```

Sometimes this runs on a file which already has a group named 'foo', in which case I see "ValueError: Unable to create group (Name already exists)"

One way to fix this is to replace the one simple line with create_group with four lines, like this:

```
if 'foo' in hdf.keys():
    g = hdf['foo']
else:
    g = hdf.create_group['foo']

g.create_dataset(...etc...)
```

Is there a neater way to do this, maybe in only one line? Like how with files in the standard C library, 'a' mode will either append to an existing file, or create a file if it's not already there.

Same goes for datasets - I have

```
create_dataset('bar', ...)
```

but should check first:

```
if 'bar' in g.keys():
   d = g['bar']
else:
   d = g.create_dataset('bar')
```

My wish: to find h5py has methods named  create_or_use_group()  and create_or_use_dataset().   What actually exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753418/check-if-node-exists-in-h5py

Comment: No, that question just asks about testing if a node exists.  I want to have it created, or use it, without writing out an 'if' statement, ideally in one line.

Answer (score 5):

Yes: [`require_group`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.require_group) and [`require_dataset`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.require_dataset):

```py
with h5py.File("/tmp/so_hdf5/test2.h5", 'w') as f:
    a = f.create_dataset('a',data=np.random.random((10, 10)))

with h5py.File("/tmp/so_hdf5/test2.h5", 'r+') as f:
    a = f.require_dataset('a', shape=(10, 10), dtype='float64')
    d = f.require_dataset('d', shape=(20, 20), dtype='float64')
    g = f.require_group('foo')
    print(a)
    print(d)
    print(g)
```

Note that you do need to know the shape and dtype of the dataset, otherwise `require_dataset` throws a `TypeError`. In that case, you could do something like:

```py
try:
    a = f.require_dataset('a', shape=(10, 10), dtype='float64')
except TypeError:
    a = f['a']
```

If you don't already know the shape and dtype, I don't think there's much advantage to `require_dataset` over using `try ... except ...`